# Convert excel to CSV - punctuation/indentation problem

Tags: excel, csv

I have excel file which looks like below -

[image]

I am converting this excel file to csv -> Using "Save As" -> CSV UTF-8 (Comma-delimeted)(*.csv)

After saving once I open this file in Notepad++ , it looks like below :

[image]

Issue is "ITCF Control Description" value for second row start with Double quotes even in original excel there is no double quotes.
"Documented and approved procedures are in place that define the process for the backup, storage and recovery of information systems, application and data. The procedures are periodically reviewed."

Most important : Attribute description value in second row also starts with double quotes and end of double quote goes to next line.
[image]

Due to this there is blank row getting inserted in the csv because double quotes move to next line. how to resolve this ?

Comment: That is because there is a comma in the sentence.  If it is saved without the quotes it will split on the comma in the sentence.

Comment: And I would suspect the comment that was deleted about cell D3 to also be correct.  There is probably a carriage return in that cell that you do not see.

Comment: Excel SaveAs CSV processes data in a particular way, giving the output you see (Scotts given you the why for that). The real question is: what are you going to do with that CSV (presumably it's an input to another system)? Does it cope with the file Excel produced? If it doesn't, then you will need to either pre-process the data in the sheet, or not use SaveAs and generate the required output yourself

Comment: What are the other options i have apart from "Save As" ?